# How send Ethereum transaction with python without ganache?

Tags: python, linux, blockchain, ethereum, ether

Im new at this blockchain thing and want to learn it with python

i arleady created a wallet via python

Now my question: Is it possible to send transaction with this information

- mnemonic
- adress
- entropy
- private_key
- public key
- passphrase

thank you for help :)

Comment: Use Web3.py library: https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to know the private key and using web3.py.
Please follow the documentation: https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html?highlight=sign#sign-a-transaction